# Web Start Application: Concurrency Issue

Tags: java, concurrency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Part-2: Web Start Application: Concurrency Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736530/part-2-web-start-application-concurrency-issue)

I have developed a GUI tool in Java which does some operation (such as insert row, retrieve row, update row...) on MS Excel. I have neither used thread programming and nor any locking mechanism in this tool.

This tool was deployed as windows exe and now I have deployed as Web Start Application.
Many people access this tool at the sametime and do operation on that excel file (a shared resource among all people) simultaneusly.

Recently this tool currupted the excel file because two people were writing on excel file at the same time (I got to know from the timestamp in the logs).

One person was updating some record and another person was inserting a new record. Both operations happened almost at the sametime on the same excel file. Now I think that the shared excel file was corrupted bcoz concurrency issues.

Can you please help me what I suppose to do in this case? How I fix this problem? Is there a simple way to fix this issue?

Many Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: If you really want to fix this issue throw away the shared excel file - you need a database!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however its an obligation to use excel file in my scenario. :(

Comment: @user981116: quit the job - asap :-) This will never scale, it's just an architectural nightmare!

Comment: @user981116 then either use google spreadsheet with proper security or use many of the open source web enabled spreadsheet libraries (ZK has one)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to learn about file locks. Here is an example to get you started quickly.

> http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/SetFileLock.html

Comment: You can use file locks but not the right solution.

Comment: @Pangea I agree. Using a Database to would be much more scalable but he wants a simple way to fix the problem. Maybe he just has 2 users writing to a excel file.

Comment: that is why I upvoted...but wanted to leave a comment to make sure the OP doesn't ignore alternate solutions

Comment: Thanks for your reply and pointers! As I mentioned earlier in my scenario database is not appropriate bcoz application is for business people and they love to see things in excel. If the File Lock is the only solution left, then will dig in this. If need more information, will come back you guys. if you have other idea, please feel free to let me know. many thanks