# Part-2: Web Start Application: Concurrency Issue

Tags: java, file, locking

With your suggestions given on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667166/web-start-application-concurrency-issue/7736364#7736364),

I tried using FileLock, however, when I write something in the file, somehow excel file gets corrupted and there is nothing in the file (it gets empty, no contents in there)

I have the following method:

```
void writeIntoTheFile(XSSFWorkbook defectWorkBook, File fileToWrite) {

            FileLock lock = null;
            FileChannel channel = null;
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                //fileToWrite contains an excel .xlsx file
                channel = new RandomAccessFile(fileToWrite, "rw").getChannel();
                lock = channel.tryLock();
                if (lock != null) {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(fileToWrite.getPath());
                    defectWorkBook.write(out);

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Another instance is already writing, Try after a few seconds.", "Write Error...", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                    out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            } 


           finally{   
            if (lock != null && lock.isValid()) {
                    lock.release();
                }
            channel.close();

            } 

        }
```

Seems the problem is coming from below code:

```
channel = new RandomAccessFile(fileToWrite, "rw").getChannel();
 lock = channel.tryLock();
```

Can anyone please help me on this issue?

rahul

Comment: Next time, just edit your _original_ question with the additional information. I'm closing that one in favor of this, as this question is much more clearly asked.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are getting an exception in your try{} block, but your catch clock doesn't prin it. *e.getMessage()* will get the message but not print it.

I suggest something along the lines of *e.printStackTrace()* (for a production system you would want to do something more useful with the exception).

Comment: No, I tried debugging code. the flow does not go thru catch. The problem was in out = new FileOutputStream(fileToWrite.getPath());
When I added "true" for append, then excel xlsx workbook was not corrupted. out = new FileOutputStream(fileToWrite.getPath(), true);
But still the data is not written in excel sheet..
I checked while debugging the values in the rows and cells of MS excel workbook sheet (defectWorkBook), but somehow they are not written on this statement defectWorkBook.write(out); No exception is thrown at all. not sure why its not written in the actual file.